# global.asax session_start not firing in angularjs app

Tags: c#, angularjs, session, global-asax

I have single page application using Angularjs and c#, all pages in the application have html extension not aspx, when I run it Session_Start event in Global.asax is not firing at all.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your pages are plain html, there's really no ASP.NET component to your application. No `Session_Start` event will ever fire unless you make an ASP.NET request that requires a session to be created. If you make a server request that loads an ASP.NET resource (aspx page, MVC controller route), you should have a session initiated.

Comment: My page actually calls controller, but it doesn't rigger Session_Start: `$http.get('api/travel/').success(function (data) {
        $scope.travelList = data;
        $scope.tripType = 2;
    }).error(function () {
        //alert(data);
        alert('Error reading JSON file.');
    });`

Comment: I'm guessing by the naming of your controller route that it's a Web Api Controller, not an MVC Controller. Web Api does not use session  state (not by default, at least).

Comment: You are correct it is Web Api controller, so what should be my approach in this case?